# spawning more objects in love2d?

Tags: lua, love2d

so, i'm a beginner with love2d coding but i think i've got most of the basics down.

however, i don't know how i would go about creating a function//table to spawn in multiple objects at a time.

```
function love.load()
    local music = love.audio.newSource('flamingo.mp3')
    music:setLooping(true)
    love.audio.play(music)
    player = {}
    player.x = 5
    player.y = 225
    player.speed = 2
    player.image = love.graphics.newImage('player.png')

    flower = {}
    flower.image = love.graphics.newImage('flower.png')
    flower.x = love.math.random(0, 400)
    flower.y = love.math.random(0, 250)
end

function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown('right') then
        player.x = player.x + player.speed
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('left') then
        player.x = player.x - player.speed
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('up') then
        player.y = player.y - player.speed
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('down') then
        player.y = player.y + player.speed
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(flower.image, flower.x, flower.y)
    love.graphics.draw(player.image, player.x, player.y)
end
```

i have a table that spawns in one flower, but i'd like to spawn more in (random number of flowers with a random x,y position) and like i said, i don't know how so i'd love some help.

Answer (score 0):

By adding more tables of course!

```
function love.load()
    --....
    flower = {}
    flower.image = love.graphics.newImage('flower.png')
    flower.x = love.math.random(0, 400)
    flower.y = love.math.random(0, 250)

    flower1 = {}
    flower1.image = love.graphics.newImage('flower.png')
    flower1.x = love.math.random(0, 400)
    flower1.y = love.math.random(0, 250)

    flower2={}
    --etc...
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(flower.image, flower.x, flower.y)
    love.graphics.draw(flower1.image, flower1.x, flower1.y)
    --etc...
    love.graphics.draw(player.image, player.x, player.y)
end
```

Seriously, though, you probably can see some problems with the above approach. 
Description, explanation and education on how to organize code better than that would be fit for a good textbook, not a SO answer.

There are already numerous books and guides out there. Make sure you understand at least the [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) and look for example [here](https://github.com/SSYGEN/blog/issues/30) to see how a similar program can be structured. Keep in mind, that, ideally, there's still much to be learned in addition (and in-between) those links.